# Pulling $_POST array elements into sequential variables with a common prefix

Tags: php, post, arrays, arraylist

I have a $_POST array that results from selecting (in this case) 3 rows from a displayed HTML table in which each row has a checkbox.  The IDs are unique identifiers for each row.

```
Array
(
    [checkbox] => Array
        (
            [0] => 001403166
            [1] => 001407509
            [2] => 001407541
        )
)
```

I want to gather the IDs into variables so that I can go back and pull the full rows from mysql for processing (e.g., delete, etc.) -- something like ~

```
$var1 = 001403166
$var2 = 001407509
$var3 = 001407541
```

I haven't a clue as to how to do this (not unusual), or even what it is called so that I can find information about it.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [extract](http://php.net/extract) function should do almost what you're asking :

```
int extract  ( array $var_array  [, int $extract_type = EXTR_OVERWRITE  [, string $prefix  ]] )
```

> Import variables from an array into
>   the current symbol table.

Something like this, I suppose, should do the trick :

```
extract($_POST['checkbox'], EXTR_PREFIX_ALL , 'var');
```

Only thing is that you'll get variables called `$var_0`, `$var_1`, `$var_2` :

- counting from `0`, and not from `1`, as the keys in `$_POST['checkbox']` start from `0`.
- and with a '`_`' between `$var` and the number.

Note : before using `extract`, you should make sure `$_POST['checkbox']` only contains "clean" data !

Comment: I have used extract() previously, but I was not familiar with its real capabilities.  Your solution works very nicely.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :-) Have fun ! *(but don't forget that using `extract` can lead to troubles, if the data you're using it on is not clean/safe ! )*

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider imploding this array into a single string, and using your databases native `IN()` function to cut down on running a single request for each individual row.

```
$uniqueIDs = array(1111,1222,1333);
$idString  = implode(",",$uniqueIDs);

$query = "SELECT id, col1, col2 
          FROM tableName
          WHERE id IN ({$idString})";
```

This query will come out to be:

```
SELECT id, col1, col2 
FROM tableName 
WHERE id IN (1111,1222,1333)
```

Selecting rows having an ID found within that list.

Comment: Now, this I had not thought of!  It is made to order for the type of thing that I'm working on.  Thank you very much!